# Understanding Collatz Conjecture Objective in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to decipher the following homework question. My code is supposed to evaluate to 190 but instead evaluates to 114. So, I don't think I'm understanding the coding requirement.

> The Collatz conjecture is an example of a simple computational process
>   whose behavior is so unpredictable that the world's best
>   mathematicians still don't understand it.
>
> Consider the simple function `f(n)` (as defined in the Wikipedia page
>   above) that takes an integer `n` and divides it by two if `n` is even and
>   multiplies `n` by 3 and then adds one to the result if `n` is odd. The
>   conjecture involves studying the value of expressions of the form
>   `f(f(f(...f(f(n)))))` as the number of calls to the function `f`
>   increases. The conjecture is that, for any non-negative integer `n`,
>   repeated application of `f` to `n` yields a sequence of integers that
>   always includes 1.
>
> Your task for this question is to implement the Collatz function `f` in
>   Python. The key to your implementation is to build a test that
>   determines whether `n` is even or odd by checking whether the remainder
>   when `n` is divided by 2 is either zero or one. Hint: You can compute
>   this remainder in Python using the remainder opertor `%` via the
>   expression `n % 2`. Note you will also need to use integer division `//`
>   when computing `f`.
>
> Once you have implemented `f`, test the your implementation on the
>   expression `f(f(f(f(f(f(f(674)))))))`. This expression should evaluate
>   to `190`.

```
from __future__ import division


def collatz(n):
    l = []
    l.append(n)
    while n != 1:

        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
            l.append(n)

        else:
            n = (3*n) + 1
            l.append(n)
    return l


print len(collatz(674))
```

Comment: You have not implemented `f` but an entirely different (although related) function. `f` should just calculate the next term in the sequence, not the entire sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just misread the intermediary question. Your programs tries to answer the bigger question... This is what should return `190`:

```
def f(n):
    return n // 2 if n % 2 == 0 else 3*n + 1


print f(f(f(f(f(f(f(674)))))))
```